# Padding not enlarging container

Tags: css

I have created css popup that is 80% of the body, at the bottom of a website, with fixed height. It is placed always at the end of the body element.

```
...
<div style="width: 80%; height: 200px;">
   <div style="width: 32%; padding: 0 0 0 40px;">
   <div style="width: 32%; padding: 0 0 0 40px;">
   <div style="width: 32%; padding: 0 0 0 40px;">
</div>
</body>
```

I add this code dynamically through javascript.

When I display it on two separate pages:
1. On 1 page changing padding enlarges the container - so changing padding from 40 to 60 will move boxes to the right.
2. On 2 page changing padding doesn't move other containers to the right, but instead it makes elements smaller inside this container.

Why is that so? What could be the reason?

Comment: any `box-sizing` somewhere? It could be that there is a `box-sizing:border-box;` somewhere

Comment: To expand on what @KhanhTO said, `box-sizing: border-box;` causes padding (among other things, such as borders) to be applied to the inside of the element. Worth noting that this is highly desirable in most circumstances. Without this CSS property the padding will be applied to the outside of the element, thereby expanding it.

Comment: @khernik will you provide just an example code for this.?